# Openfeign How to use @Headers annotation with different produces and consumes types?

Tags: java, feign, openfeign

I want to use Feign client in my project but some endpoints produces `text/plain` while consuming `application/json`. Right now I have something like this. Method is producing `plain/text` and will consume `application/json`. Is there a way to fix it? Note that this is not a Spring boot application. It's just a Java/Maven project.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: text/plain")
@RequestLine(value = "POST /containers/{id}/services")
String startService(@Param("id") String id, String serviceType);
```

In Jaxrs we use below headers to specify the mime types that this method or class uses.

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

I want to be able to do same thing but there is no Produces or consumes headers in feign client. There is only @Headers there you can specify content type. I wonder if this annotation's `Content-Type` is used for both consuming and producing, or just for consuming, or if you can specify different types for both producing and consuming?

Comment: It's kinda hard to understand what you want to achieve from the question. Could you please provide an expected result or make the question more verbose?

Comment: @amseager I updated my question. I hope it makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

@Headers content should look like this:

```
@Headers({
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: text/plain",
})
```

With `Accept` header in place, you tell feign client to produce `JSON` (in your case it is `serviceType` passed into the method) and consume `text/plain`.